# azure logic app expression for entire object after parse JSON action

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I have a azure logic app that receives an input json string. I would like to pass this over to a JSON to Table action. However, I am having difficulties as the JSON to Table needs an input of type object. After researching I thought I need to parse the string first and then give the body of the parse json action as the input to the JSON to Table action.

[image]

[image]

I am not sure what the correct expression for the entire JSON object after the Parse JSON action is. I have tried with @{body('Parse_JSON')} (what chatgbt suggestsed) but it gives 'invalid expression'. Would anyone know the correct expression?

On another note, I've noticed that when I manually insert the entire string in the Data field of JSON to Table it works fine. When I intiated a variable of type object with the string as the value it worked as well. However, I have not found a way to integrate to Content of my trigger. When I pass the Content directy to the JSON to Table I get the error: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer'.

My input string looks something like this:

```
{
  "comment": null,
  "data": {
    "id": "123",
    "Person": {
      "Name": "Testmann",
      "Firstname": "Tim"
    },
    "Timestamp": "2023-03-22T20:16:04.663252+01:00",
    "Fotos_Apppletree": [
      {
        "photo_description_1": null,
        "_1_Foto_Appletree": {
          "fileId": "10",
          "fileName": "Appletree_2023_03_22_19_16_09.png",
          "timestamp": "2023-03-22T19:16:09.082243Z",
          "size": 63865,
          "url": "https://path10"
        }
      },
      {
        "photo_description_2": null,
        "_1_Foto_Appletree": {
          "fileId": "11",
          "fileName": "Appletree_2023_03_22_19_16_15.png",
          "timestamp": "2023-03-22T19:16:15.082243Z",
          "size": 63865,
          "url": "https://path11"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to tackle this string/object problem. Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Can you add your expected output for above json and I guess as this is not a regular json , you need to do manually(for that you can use Create html table connector ).

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by regenerating the shema of the parse json so then the body expression worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree @Anna that Parse_Json Shemea generation is the key here,

**`My Design:`**

[image]

**`Parse Json Schema:`**

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "comment": {},
        "data": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Person": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "Firstname": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Timestamp": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Fotos_Apppletree": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "photo_description_1": {},
                            "_1_Foto_Appletree": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "fileId": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "fileName": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "timestamp": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "size": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "url": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "photo_description_2": {}
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "_1_Foto_Appletree"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next you can use your step of Json to Table.

**`Output Of Parse Json:`**

[image]

Then you can use Json to table with advanced connector , or you can use below connector also:

[image]